# installed openstack using devstack install shell script but getting 500 error when i try opening dashboard

Tags: ubuntu, openstack

I followed the instructions at http://devstack.org/guides/single-machine.html to install OpenStack.

I first installed Ubuntu on my Windows 7 PC using the officially supported Windows installer for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. And after that I followed the instructions at above page to install OpenStack.

As per instructions, I should be able to access the dashboard aka Horizon, at `http://192.168.1.4/` (thats the IP of the PC on which I installed Ubuntu->OpenStack).

However I am getting a 500 error web page when I open that.

How do I resolve this error? I want to set up a dev environment for OpenStack.

For your ref, the whole error message is given now--

```
FilterError at /
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.4/
Django Version: 1.4.2
Exception Type: FilterError
Exception Value:    
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/filters/base.py in     input, line 133
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../..',
 '/opt/stack/python-keystoneclient',
 '/opt/stack/python-novaclient',
 '/opt/stack/python-openstackclient',
 '/opt/stack/keystone',
 '/opt/stack/glance',
 '/opt/stack/python-glanceclient/setuptools_git-0.4.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/stack/python-glanceclient',
 '/opt/stack/nova',
 '/opt/stack/horizon',
 '/opt/stack/cinder',
 '/opt/stack/python-cinderclient',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',
 '/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard']
Server time:    Sat, 27 Oct 2012 08:43:29 +0000


Error during template rendering

In template /opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/templates/_stylesheets.html, error at line 3
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
1   {% load compress %}
2   
3   {% compress css %}
4   <link href='{{ STATIC_URL }}dashboard/less/horizon.less' type='text/less'     media='screen' rel='stylesheet' />
5   {% endcompress %}
6   
7   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}dashboard/img/favicon.ico"/>
8
```

Also, the traceback is now given below--

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.1.4/

Django Version: 1.4.2
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('openstack_dashboard',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'compressor',
 'horizon',
 'openstack_dashboard.dashboards.project',
 'openstack_dashboard.dashboards.admin',
 'openstack_dashboard.dashboards.settings',
 'openstack_auth')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'horizon.middleware.HorizonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware')


  Template error:
  In template /opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/templates/_stylesheets.html, error at     line 3
  /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

 1 : {% load compress %}


 2 :
```

3 :  {% compress css %}

```
 4 : <link href='{{ STATIC_URL }}dashboard/less/horizon.less' type='text/less' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' />


 5 : {% endcompress %}


 6 : 


 7 : <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}dashboard/img/favicon.ico"/>


 8 : 

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args,     **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/vary.py" in     inner_func
  36.         response = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/views.py" in splash
  38.     return shortcuts.render(request, 'splash.html', {'form': form})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  44.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in     render_to_string
  176.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.         return self.render_template(self.template, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in     render_template
  137.         output = template.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/templatetags/compress.py" in render
  147.         return self.render_compressed(context, self.kind, self.mode, forced=forced)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/templatetags/compress.py" in render_compressed
  107.             rendered_output = self.render_output(compressor, mode, forced=forced)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/templatetags/compress.py" in render_output
  119.         return compressor.output(mode, forced=forced)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/css.py" in output
  51.                     ret.append(subnode.output(*args, **kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/css.py" in output
  53.         return super(CssCompressor, self).output(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/base.py" in output
  230.         content = self.filter_input(forced)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/base.py" in filter_input
  192.         for hunk in self.hunks(forced):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/base.py" in hunks
  167.                 precompiled, value = self.precompile(value, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/base.py" in precompile
  210.                     command=command, filename=filename).input(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/filters/base.py" in input
  133.                 raise FilterError(err)

Exception Type: FilterError at /
Exception Value: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/horizon/+bug/1070083) in quantal node and nodejs support in devstack (but may get fixed in horizon). Given I'm trying to do the same as you (in a VM) I got horizon working by:

1. `sudo su`
2. `cd /usr/bin`
3. `ln -s nodejs node`

This creates a symlink called `node` that points to `nodejs`. Assuming all other things are equal horizon should launch OK now.

Comment: for reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/horizon/+bug/1070083

Comment: NOTE: I took the path of do-release-upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 12.10 because devstack dependencies are supposedly looked after... so you may consider doing that as well